# How are hinted handoffs handled in Dynamo

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, distributed-system

From what I understand about hinted handoffs in Dynamo as per this [paper](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) , if a coordinator node can't write to one of the replicas it will hand off the write to another node with a hint. So consider a cluster with a replication factor 5(N) and minimum writes(W) as 3. The coordinator node will try to write to all 4 replicas. If 3 of then return success and one of them fails because of a temporary issue it hands off the write to another node with a hint to replay it to the failed replica when it comes back up. I wanted to confirm that my understanding of  what happens if the replica comes back up and the hinted node takes time to replay that row or the hinted node itself goes down is correct. Even though this failed replica is now serving outdated information, Dynamo will read from minimum read (R) no. of nodes(let's say this is 3) and pick the version that is the latest of all 3 and return it back to the client. In this way even if the hint is not replayed back the client still gets the correct information

Comment: Just to clarify, that paper is about Dynamo, which is not the same thing as DynamoDB. Are you trying to understand Dynamo or DynamoDB?

Comment: @MatthewPope Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is covered in section "4.7 Handling permanent failures: Replica synchronization".

> There are scenarios under which hinted replicas become unavailable before they can be returned to the original replica node. To handle this and other threats to durability, Dynamo implements an anti-entropy (replica synchronization) protocol to keep the replicas synchronized.

Since anti-entropy algorithms are not deterministic, I would suppose the synchronization does not happen with a hard guarantee but with a high probability nonetheless.